# Parsing a list that contains Str and Ints

Tags: python, string, list, int

What I'm trying to do is take a list like "['Smith', '13', '19', '8', '12']" and I am trying to take the int's out of it and add them all up to compute the average. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?  SO is not a free coding service; you cannot just copy/paste your homework here.  Please show us what you have tried so far and we will be more than happy to help with any specific issues you are having.

Comment: If you are the one who is responsible for this data structure: Change it!

Comment: @Mike You can accept the answer that helped you the best.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
# go through each member of your list and call the 
# builtin string method `isdigit` check out the documentation
digits = [int(s) for s in your_list if s.isdigit()]
# use the built in `sum` function and the builtin `len` function
sum(digits) / len(digits)
```

Comment: This helped out a lot, I got divide by zero on some of my questions but this allowed me understand what I was doing wrong thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `try`.

```
sum = 0
number_of_ints = 0
for items in ['Smith', '13', '19', '8', '12']:
    try:
        sum += int(items)
        number_of_ints+=1
    except:
        pass
print sum/number_of_ints
```

Basically, this trys to add it to `sum`. If it fails, it continues.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
myList = ['Smith', '13', '19', '8', '12']
count = 0
total = 0

for i in myList:
    if i.isdigit():
        count += 1
        total += int(i)

average = total / count
```